# Color the entire cell according to a particular text using conditional formatt

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

When we select a text from a drop-down list can we color the entire cell according to a particular name in that dropdown list. for eg; if we select "bolero" from drop down list. the entire row must turn red.

here is the worksheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VsLKHSZsTMeBctnINnsixKISgNkTHDV-dkO4ORsDjgI/edit#gid=1975041699

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the following formula as a conditional rule

```
=$C2="BOLERO"
```

[image]

*(If you want to use different colours for the rest of the brands/names, just create more filters like `=$C2="XUV"`)*